# Thermal Conduction and Thermal Diffusivity

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics

Hello I am designing a Aluminium fiber connector as shown below

[image]

I am tasked to maintain the object at a thermal equilibrium of 25 degrees Celsius. The object will be heated with 50W of power. I have been reading up about how much heat will a certain amount of power generate. https://sciencing.com/how-8643971-convert-wattage-degrees.html. Is this applicable to my situation?

After knowing the temperature increase due to the power source, how do I achieve a thermal equilibrium of 25 degrees Celsius? From my understanding, the thermal diffusivity must equal the rate of thermal conduction for it to be in equilibrium? I do not know how to relate the thermal diffusivity formula to thermal conduction.

Comment: If you want to maintain a specific temperature then power in = power out.

Comment: @SolarMike the power out is thermal energy diffuse to the surrounding?

Comment: The linked article shows you how to calculate the temperature rise for a given energy input. It assumes zero losses to ambient. Your situation is different as you are trying to maintain a constant temperature a little higher than room temperature. In most applications this will require adding a temperature sensor and temperature controller to make a control loop. You didn't dimension the object so we have no idea how feasible this is in your application. Your problem may be similar to temperature control of a 3D printer nozzle only at much lower temperature setpoint.

Comment: If we know the dimensions is it possible to maintain a constant temperature by just changing the material of the object? changing the variable will result in a change in the specific heat capacity thus varying the thermal conductivity and diffusivity to your desired value? Does it work this way? @Transistor

Comment: "*Changing the variable will result in a change in the specific heat capacity thus varying the thermal conductivity and diffusivity to your desired value?*" Heat loss will be affected by ambient temperature. If this changes then you need temperature control. You still have not provided dimensions. Why do you need to control the temperature of an "aluminium fiber connector"? (Periodic table elements are lowercase when spelt out.)

Comment: You need the following:  Ambient temperature & surface finish of the object (for radiation).  Then heat out needs to equal 50W.  I'm not clear how large that thing is, but 50W is a ton in any smaller device (put your hand around a 50W incandescant bulb).  If the device is smaller than about 6 cm, it will require some type of forced cooling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 50 W is being dissipated in the device, then to maintain *any* constant temperature, for *any* material, you must remove 50 W. This is independent of the material properties.

If you choose passive cooling, then the device will heat up to an equilibrium temperature for which the heat loss to the environment is 50 W. Consider the simple [lumped-capacitance model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumped-element_model), in which the material temperature is idealized as uniform (this is a reasonable assumption when the thermal conductivity is high). Assuming that heat is lost primarily through convection, then an energy balance gives $P=hA(T-T_\mathrm{env})$, where $P$ is the power, $h$ is the convective coefficient, $A$ is the surface area, $T$ is the device temperature, and $T_\mathrm{env}$ is the ambient environmental temperature.

Perhaps $h=1\,\mathrm{W}\,\mathrm{m}^{-1}\,\mathrm{K}^{-1}$ for natural convection, and perhaps $T_\mathrm{env}=20^\circ \mathrm{C}$. Then, for $P=50\,\mathrm{W}$ and a surface area of $A=0.1\,\mathrm{m}^2$, say, the equilibrium temperature is projected to be $520^\circ\mathrm{C}$. To get this down to $25^\circ\mathrm{C}$, you might have to encase the device in a block of a high-thermal-conductivity material (such as copper) to give a surface area of $A=1\,\mathrm{m}^2$ and blow gas past it to obtain a higher forced-convection coefficient of $h=10\,\mathrm{W}\,\mathrm{m}^{-1}\,\mathrm{K}^{-1}$, for example. Or you could use fins, a classic approach for increasing surface area. Alternatively, you could run coolant lines through the device or the encasing block with fluid at $<20^\circ\mathrm{C}$ to carry away the heat. But it seems clear that passive cooling alone won't be anywhere near sufficient.